# bash - find string index position of substring

Tags: linux, bash

good day all

I am not able to see my error, I would like to find the position of a substring "searchstring" within string "t"

of a few methods I have looked at, this seems easiest and most understandable however this just hangs (both)

```
awk 'match($t, "$searchstring")'

awk '{print match($t, "$searchstring")}'
```

[original post - post #3](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/56093-how-get-location-word-string.html)

- t             ="MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:44595: 10.0.0.12"
- searchstring  ="IP for"

any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
t="MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:44595: 10.0.0.12"
searchstring="IP for"

rest=${t#*$searchstring}
echo $(( ${#t} - ${#rest} - ${#searchstring} ))
```

`$rest` contains the part of `$t` *after* `$searchstring`. The starting position of the substring is therefore the length of the whole string minus the length of the `$rest` *minus the length* of the `$searchstring` itself.

Comment: thanks, this does exactly what I need, however any idea why the awk expression does not work?

Comment: `$t` is a shell variable, not expanded in single quotes, not accesible to awk.

Comment: What if `$searchstring` not exist?

Comment: @linrongbin: If the `$searchstring` is not present in the `$t`, the result will be negative.

Answer (score 5):

Even better and suitable to more cases (consider '#' versus '##' and having more than one instance of 'IP for') would be to remove from the matching string to the end and use the length of what remains.

```
text="MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:44595: 10.0.0.12"
search="IP for"

prefix=${text%%$search*}
echo ${#prefix}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
t="MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:44595: 10.0.0.12"
searchstring="IP for"

temp=${t%%$searchstring*} && indexOf=$(echo "${t%%$searchstring*}" | cat ${#temp})
echo "$indexOf"
```

Outputs:

```
23
```